# Return value and keyword inside a Parallel ForEach or For loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

What is the correct way to return a value from a Parallel ForEach or For loop?

For example is the following code correct/threadsafe?

```
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    String ProcessName = String.Empty;
    Parallel.ForEach(processes, curItem => {
        if (curItem.Handle == this._handle) {
            ProcessName = curItem.ProcessName;
            return;
        }
    });
    return ProcessName;
}
```

**OR THIS?**

```
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    List<String> ProcessNames = new List<String>();
    Parallel.ForEach(processes, curItem => {
            ProcessNames.Add(processes.ProcessName);
        }
    });
    return ProcessNames;
}
```

Lastly what is the behavior of the return keyword inside a Parallel For or ForEach loop?

IE: Does it immediately terminate all threads? Will it cause any artifacts that you might not expect?

Hopefully what I am asking makes sense.

PS: To be more specific. Looking at the first example is my modification of the String threadsafe and contain the value I expect because of the return statement? And in the second example is my modification of the List Collection threadsafe? Will all the values I expect be added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use PLINQ here:

```
return Process
    .GetProcesses()
    .AsParallel()
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Handle == this._handle);
```

I wonder whether the amount of data you're handling here merits going parallel...

To answer your question more directly, in order to handle early exit from a parallel loop you should look into overloads that hand a [ParallelLoopState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.aspx) to the executing delegate. This can be used to control early loop termination.

EDIT:

The errors you are seeing is because your process does not have sufficient privilege to access the handle of the processes you inspecting. A brute force way of handling this would be as follows:

```
Process
.GetProcesses()
//.AsParallel()
.Where(p=>{try{var h=p.Handle;}catch{return false;}return true;})
.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Handle == this._handle)
```

Of course, assuming `this._handle` refers to the handle of the currently executing process:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess()
```

would surely be a better fit?

Comment: I am just doing it to play around with the concept. I assume it probably doesn't.

Comment: Is it just me? The above code throws the following error: Win32Exception was unhandled by user code. Access is denied - I'm guessing it has something to do with comparing handles?

Comment: Not in my case, I have a my own custom Window class. It implements functionality the process object doesn't provide. I was just trying to avoid another API call and playing around with the concept. It looks like it doesn't work in a standard loop either. Whoops!

Answer (score 7):

`return` inside a parallel foreach loop is basically the same as a `continue` in a normal loop, because the `return` is inside the delegate that is executed for each item. This means, it doesn't terminate any threads and especially doesn't terminate execution of the parallel foreach loop.

Answer (score 6):

All of above answers +:

If you want to signal that loop should stop, you should use `ParallelLoopState` (you can access this object by passing `Action<T, ParallelLoopState>` instead of `Action<T>` delegate. State object has method like `.Stop()` or `.Break()` that will signal that you want to stop executing your loop (and few other useful properties, try it by yourself).

Answer (score 5):

Neither is correct. You are searching a value? `Parallel.ForEach` is the wrong solution here. What you are looking for is a [reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_%28higher-order_function%29), while `ForEach` performs a [mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29). A parallel reduction can be performed using PLINQ.